# query string not fully read in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, curl, libcurl

i have ruby on rails based api which accepts a get request. 
example :

```
http://localhost:3000/api/search?query=whatis&access_token=324nbkjh3g32423
```

when i do curl from mac terminal like

```
curl http://localhost:3000/api/search?query=whatis&access_token=324nbkjh3g32423
```

i checked in the server with "`request.fullpath`", it return only "`/api/search?query=whatis`", the second parameter is missing.

however if i do curl like

```
curl --data="query=whatis&access_token=324nbkjh3g32423" http://localhost:3000/api/search
```

it is taking all the parameters.

i understand there is a problem with encoding, but i what to know what difference is there with the two requests.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is that `bash` shell sees `&` as the end of the command.

try quoting the entire querystring like this -

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/api/search?query=whatis&access_token=324nbkjh3g32423"
```